# How can I add external stylesheet into a svg file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to add a style-sheet into svg file. And the style-sheet will be change dynamically. Because my idea is I want to change the icons fill or stock color by changing theme.  What is the process I need to follow?

Comment: Are you sure you used google? (http://www.sitepoint.com/svg-styling-with-css/).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you would just control the SVG and its elements like any other element on the page, this is assuming your SVG is inline.

So say we have our svg:

```
<svg id="my_icon" class="red-theme" height="100" width="100" fill="red">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

And we had 2 themes, red theme and a blue theme.
Then we would create the 2 styles in CSS:

```
.red-theme{
  fill: red;
}
.blue-theme{
  fill: blue;
}
```

We can then use jQuery (in this example but you could use other options) to dynamically change the theme by changing the svg's theme on a button press.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var p_class = $('#my_icon').attr('class')
  if (p_class == 'red-theme'){
    $('#my_icon').attr('class', 'blue-theme')
  } else {
    $('#my_icon').attr('class', 'red-theme')
  }
});
```

All together it would look something like this:

http://codepen.io/ballerton/pen/GZGrZe

Hope this helps.